# Get order id by order increment id in Magento 2

Tags: magento2.2, sales-order, object-manager, increment-id

I want to get order id by order increment id. I have this code but it is returning empty value:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$incrId = 100005363;
$collection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order'); 
$orderInfo = $collection->loadByIncrementId($incrId);
$orderId = $orderInfo->getOrderId();
echo $orderId;
```

What is the wrong with code or I am doing some wrong approach?

Comment: Please use, $orderId = $orderInfo->getId();

Comment: @ArshadHussain, If answer is helpful please accept and upvote

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try below Code

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$incrId = 100005363;
$collection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order'); 
$orderInfo = $collection->loadByIncrementId($incrId);
$orderId = $orderInfo ->getId();
echo $orderId;
```

Comment: Object manager should be avoided.

Answer (score 11):

You don't need to get the collection of order instead use `\Magento\Sales\Model\Spi\OrderResourceInterface` to get a single order object

```
use Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface;

class Mageprince
{
    private $orderResource;
    private $orderFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Spi\OrderResourceInterface $orderResource,
        \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterfaceFactory $orderFactory
    ){
        $this->orderResource = $orderResource;
        $this->orderFactory = $orderFactory;
    }

    public function getOrder()
    {
        $incrementId = '000000001';
        $order = $this->orderFactory->create();
        $this->orderResource->load($order, $incrementId, OrderInterface::INCREMENT_ID);
        return $order;
    }
}
```

Comment: `Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface` does not include the `loadByIncrementId()` method so you are depending on a specific realization from `Magento\Sales\Model\Order` which wraps the deprecated `Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel::load()`.

Answer (score 9):

I would not use any of the current answers as they [rely on model’s `load()` method that has been deprecated since 2.1](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Model/AbstractModel.php#L527-L529). Here are two ways you could do it using future-proof approaches:

1. Use the order repository if you don’t need to load detailed attributes and don’t care about memoization of the order data for later use.

   ```
    use Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface;

    class Example
    {
        protected $orderRepository;
        protected $searchCriteriaBuilder;

        public function __construct(
            \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository,
            \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder
        ){
            $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
            $this->searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
        }

        public function getOrderByIncrementId($incrementId): ?OrderInterface
        {
            $criteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder
                ->addFilter(OrderInterface::INCREMENT_ID, $incrementId)
                ->create();
            $orders = $this->orderRepository->getList($criteria)->getItems();
            return count($orders)? $orders[0] : null;
        }
    }
   ```
2. Otherwise, you could use the resource model interface.

   ```
    use Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface;

    class Example
    {
        protected $orderResource;
        protected $orderFactory;

        public function __construct(
            \Magento\Sales\Model\Spi\OrderResourceInterface $orderResource,
            \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterfaceFactory $orderFactory
        ){
            $this->orderResource = $orderResource;
            $this->orderFactory = $orderFactory;
        }

        public function getOrderByIncrementId($incrementId): OrderInterface
        {
            $order = $this->orderFactory->create();
            $this->orderResource->load($order, $incrementId, OrderInterface::INCREMENT_ID);
            return $order;
        }
    }
   ```

Once you have an instance of the order model, you can get the ID like this: `$order->getId()`.

Answer (score 2):

**Use below code to get order id by order increment id in Magento 2.**

```
<?php
namespace Package\Module\Model;


use Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory;

class Test
{
    /**
     * @var OrderFactory
     */
    protected $orderFactory;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory $orderFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        OrderFactory $orderFactory
    ) {
        $this->orderFactory = $orderFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Get order id by increment id
     *
     * @param void
     * @return int $orderId
     */
    public function getOrder($incrementId)
    {
        $orderModel = $this->orderFactory->create();
        $order = $orderModel->loadByIncrementId($incrementId);
        $orderId = $order->getId();
        return $orderId;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best (optimized) way to get order id i.e `sales_order.entity_id` from increment id by creating a custom DB query in Magento2.

1. Create a `GetOrderIdByIncrementId` class:

```php
<?php
declare(strict_types =1);

namespace Adapttive\SalesOrder\Model\Order;

use Exception;
use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order as OrderResource;

/**
 * Class GetOrderIdByIncrementId: To get order.entity_id by order.increment_id
 * Reference from \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderIncrementIdChecker
 */
class GetOrderIdByIncrementId
{
    /**
     * @var OrderResource
     */
    private $resource;

    /**
     * @param OrderResource $resource
     */
    public function __construct(OrderResource $resource)
    {
        $this->resource = $resource;
    }

    /**
     * Get order id by order increment id.
     *
     * @param string|int $incrementId
     * @return int
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     */
    public function get($incrementId): int
    {
        $result = 0;

        try {
            /** @var  \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface $adapter */
            $adapter = $this->resource->getConnection();
            $bind = [':increment_id' => $incrementId];
            /** @var \Magento\Framework\DB\Select $select */
            $select = $adapter->select();
            $select->from($this->resource->getMainTable(), $this->resource->getIdFieldName())
                ->where('increment_id = :increment_id');
            $entityId = $adapter->fetchOne($select, $bind);
            if ($entityId > 0) {
                $result = (int)$entityId;
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $result = 0;
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

2. Usage:

```php
$orderId = $this->getOrderIdByIncrementId->get($orderIncrementId)
```

Reference: https://adapttive.com/blog/magento-2-get-order-id-by-increment-id/